# Facebook Timeline : Javascript iterate over multiple arrays and output them all in a staggered manner

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Im trying to build something along the lines of facebooks timeline, I want to output a lot of different kinds of posts but I dont want them to be the same every (n)th post.

This function here is a very good representation of what im trying to achieve albeit it needs you to have fixed size arrays

`https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#JavaScript`

The 3 test kinds of timeline data I have will be:

`Array 1` - [ ["user A just liked user B"], ["User B just liked...."]...]

`Array 2` - [ ["user C posted a status update"], ["user A posted a status update..."]...]

`Array 3` - [ ["user D posted a new album"], ["user C posted a new album..."]...]

`Array 4` - [ ["user D posted a new recommendation"], ["user B posted a new recommendation"]...]

... and so on and so forth

there can be any number of, what we will call parent arrays i.e `Array 1`, `Array 2`,`Array 3`,`Array 4` these parent arrays will contain arrays themselves and sometimes multidimensional arrays however I only care about organisation of the parent arrays :)

so basically it has to follow some kind of order, I dont want the parent arrays to be organised randomly (which would simplify things greatly)

The output I would like to achieve is for `Array 1` to output every second turn `(do-able with array1 % 2 == 0)` with all the other array items to be staggered in between, but what if we run out of array 1 items while there is more of the others, well I want them to just continue outputting until maybe a new item gets input into array 1

Comment: Do you want arrays with more items to get "visited" more frequently, or are they all to be treated equally (except array 1 which seems special)?

Comment: *"but I dont want them to be the same every (n)th post."*: I don't understand this part.

Comment: Sorry yes I think its more appropriate to say I want them treated equally. The main idea is that users wont see the same type of content every time they scroll. it has to be a different array item each time so there is an order to it.. and if one array runs out of items it just continues to iterate through everything else until there is no longer anything in any array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that iterates through those arrays and takes the next value from the next subarray that still has a next value, and adds it to the result array (that it will return):

```js
const mix = (all) =>
    Array.from({length: Math.max(...all.map(arr => arr.length))}, (_, i) => 
        all.map(arr => arr[i]).filter(Boolean)
    ).flat(2);

// Sample data
const all = [
    [ ["user A just liked user B"], ["User B just liked user C"]],
    [ ["user C posted a status update"], ["user A posted a status update"], ["user B posted a status update"]],
    [ ["user D posted a new album"], ["user C posted a new album"]],
    [ ["user D posted a new recommendation"], ["user B posted a new recommendation"], ["user A posted a new recommendation"], ["user C posted a new recommendation"]]
];

console.log(mix(all));
```

So, this is what happens:

1. Find the length of the array that has the most items
2. Create a new array of that length and for each entry *i* perform steps 3 and 4 to populate it (with a new sub array):
3. Create a new array that consists of as many values as there are arrays in the input. For each one collect the *i<sup>th</sup>* element from it.
4. Kick out the `undefined` values collected in the previous step.
5. After step 2 completes, flatten the resulting array.